# Node Express Server returns "FALSE"

Tags: node.js, express, amd-processor

I just moved all my files over to a new AMD pc and installed node.  When I go to run a nodejs file or launch express server just returns "false."  Tried Windows Terminal/bash/cmd, any ideas?

```
PS C:\Users\ethan\Projects\terrariumControl> node .\testServer.js
false
```

Simple Express Server Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const apiServer = express();
const path = require('path');

const SERVERPORT = process.env.PORT || 4500;

apiServer.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/")));

apiServer.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/display.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

apiServer.listen(SERVERPORT, () => console.log(`API SERVER listening on port: ${SERVERPORT}`));

module.exports = {
    apiServer: apiServer,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a project, You should also copy the "User Settings from previous users configurations ,also  "version based".

It is not only the copying the project folder.